# chrome extension correct implementation of two asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

hope to be fine

im not perfect in javascript and i have a question with two asynchronous function in developing a chrome extension.

well ; i want to implement functionality in a chrome extenstion which is when a user clicked on a button a new tab should be created and when the page is completely loaded i need to send message to the content script of that page.

the problem is in the create tab function of chrome extension , information of the new created tab will be sent in the callback function and i cannot save that tab id in global variable on the other hand for understanding when the page is completely loaded there is a listener which will listen on the status of the tabs again information of these tabs will be sent in the callback i dont know how to relate these two function together because i cannot save the information of tab id in global variable.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        if (info.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
    }
});


chrome.tabs.create({ url: someurl , active: false },function(tab){

});
```

again thank you guys.
i appreciate any help because really i get confused and read many articles and  tried a lot of ways but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try chaining the asynchronous callbacks like:

```
//first create the tab
chrome.tabs.create({url: someurl, active:false}, function(tab){
    //once the tab is created, inject the content script
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:'yourContentScript.js'}, function(result){
        //as per default, the content script will run AFTER the page has loaded
        //once the content script has run and set up the listener, send the message
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {message:'hello, content script'});
    });
});
```

or you can use a global variable, assuming you have set `"runAt":"document_idle"` for your content script in your manifest:

```
var myTabId;

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (info.status === 'complete' && tabId == myTabId) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, msg);
    }
});


chrome.tabs.create({ url: someurl , active: false },function(tab){
    myTabId = tab.id;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer But That doesnt fix my problem first because i already have content_script that inject to all pages , so there is no need to inject that again when the page is created. and as you know content_script load when the page is completely loaded which is what i want i think in this way the script will be injected before page completely loaded. 

am i right?
i want to do something with the page when the dom elements completely loaded

Comment: i didnt know about that run_at
i didnt test that but it seems with this fix we can use global variable thanks a million.